# How to prevent cross-site scripting using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I want to stop cross-site scripting on a text area. The code below as input data will be vulnerable for the text area:

```
<script>alert("Hello")</script>
```

Can anybody help on this to prevent the cross-site scripting with a sample code??

Answer (score 2):

Cross side scripting attack is much bigger than you think and definetly not limited to code you mentioned `<script>alert("Hello")</script>`.So strictly confined to your question these type of XSS attacks can be prevented by so many php libraries.I will mention a few below.

- HTML Purifier
- PHP AntiXSS
- xssprotect
- XSS HTML Filter
- xss_clean.php filter
- Updating php version

Lets talk about the most prominant method to prevent XSS attack which is **Php AntiXss**

> PHP Anti-XSS Library developing for prevent the XSS(Cross Site
>   Scripting) vulnerabilities on the web applications. PHP Anti-XSS
>   Library automatically detect the encoding of the data that you want
>   filter and if you wish its encoding your data again. Also there are 3
>   type of filtering option.

3 Types of filtering options here

1. Blacklist Filtering
2. Whitelist Filtering
3. Graylist Filtering

Usage:

*Method 1:* 
Setting the encoding of the data

```
$data = AntiXSS::setEncoding($data, "UTF-8");
```

*Method 2:*

Setting the filter for the data

```
$data = AntiXSS::setFilter($data, "whitelist", "string");
```

---

**Popular Usage:**

Xssescape is a package used to prevent cross site scripting (xss) attack in cross brower.

Usage :

```
npm install xssescape
```

app.js

```
var xs = require('xssescape')
var htmlStr = "<script> alert(document.cookie); </script>";
   xs.strictEscape(htmlStr);
```

or

```
var htmlStr = "<script> alert(document.cookie); </script>";
   xs.unescape(htmlStr);
```

or

```
var browserURL = "http://example.com/?<script> document.cookie </script>";
   xs.unSafeUrl('/home');   // eg. you can keep what ever you want as a path name.

   // it will reload/refresh the page  with /home after the default url.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sai kiran ! Can we do this without using any library..I need to attain this in javascript only.

Comment: @Raj i will exercise on this issue and report you soon.As far as i know we need to use some or other library.